# Set filters from user and get results after processing with the data of the objects (django form)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, forms, django-filter

I would like to have your help in this part of my project:

I am trying to get results based on the filters that a user puts in a form (is it html form or modelform?). Then, I make some actions to process with the input data of the user and display some results based on these filters.

To be more specific, I have created several instances of the below model:

```
class Task(models.Model):             
    Taskdetails = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    asset = models.ForeignKey('Asset', null=True      

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

and

```
class Asset(models.Model):    
    Assetdescription= models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)         
    def __str__(self):
            return str(self.id)
```

So in my DB, there are plenty of Tasks created. Each Task has a single Asset.

The problems i face are:

1. I want the user to choose an asset from a dropdown menu. This will happen in a simple html form? Can I do that with Modelform?
2. These data will be sent to the view and processed. For example for the asset that the user has chosen, I would like to display the number of tasks in another template that belongs to this particular asset.

To sum up, the way I imagine the process is:

a. The user chooses one asset from a form.

b. The user presses the button "results"

c. According to the asset, the search of how many tasks are bound with the tasks starts. (this happens in view?)

d. In the second template, the number of the tasks will be appeared.

Are there any suggestions, guidances that may be useful?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you completed the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/)? All of what you ask (and more) are there.

Comment: I think I did!! Can you guide me which particular part can help me to this?

Comment: More specifically [part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/) and [part 4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial04/).

Comment: Yes, you need a ModelForm, combine it with a Classbased FormView, after saving, redirect to another view that shows the results as you like

Comment: In the tutorial, it appears to do that with an Html Form and not with a model form. The thing is that I am searching the model instances so I think I have to make a model form. Well I think I have difficulties in understanding the view code.